# How to transpose data with multiple observations for the id variable in SAS?

Tags: sas, transpose

I am wondering the best way to transpose data in SAS when I have multiple occurances of my id variable.  I know I can use the let option in the proc transpose statement to do this, but I do not want to get rid of any data, as I intend to compute averages.

Here is an example of my data and my code:

```
data grades;
input student testnum grade;
cards;
1   1   30
1   1   25
1   2   45
1   3   67
2   1   22
2   2   63
2   2   12
2   2   77
3   1   22
3   1   17
3   2   14
3   4   17
;
run;

proc sort data=grades;
    by student testnum;
run;

proc transpose data=grades out=trgrades;
    by student;
    id testnum;
    var grade;
run;
```

Here is how I would like my resulting dataset to look:

```
student testnum1 testnum2 testnum3 testnum4   avg12     avg34
1         30        45      67       .         33.33     67    
1         25        .        .       .         33.33     67
2         22        63       .       .         43.5      .
2         .         12       .       .         43.5      .
2         .         77       .       .         43.5      .
3         22        14       .      17         53        17
3         17        .        .       .         53        17
```

I want to use this new dataset (not sure how yet) to create the new columns that are the average score of all testnum1's and testnum2's for a student (avg12) and the average of all testenum3's and testnum4's (avg34) for a student.

There may be a much more efficient way to do this but I am stumped.
Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you really need is the average of all test 1's and 2's, and 3's and 4's for each student, then you don't need to transpose at all. All you need is a simple data step:

```
data grouped;
   set grades;
   if testnum In (1,2) then group=1;
   else if testnum in (3,4) then group=2;
run;
```

Then a basic `proc means`:

```
proc means data=grouped;
   by student group;
   var grade;
   output out=averages mean=groupaverage;
run;
```

If you need the averages in a single observation, you can easily transpose the `averages` dataset.

```
proc transpose data=grades out=trgrades;
    by student;
    id group;
    var grade;
run;
```

---

Update:

As mentioned by @Keith, using a format to group the tests is an excellent choice as well. Skip the data step and create the format like so:

```
proc format;
   value TestGroup
      1,2 = 'Tests 1 and 2'
      3,4 = 'Tests 3 and 4'
   ;
run;
```

Then the `proc means` becomes:

```
proc means data=grouped;
   by student testnum;
   var grade;
   format testnum TestGroup.;
   output out=averages mean=groupaverage;
run;
```

End Update

---

If, for some reason, you really need to have all the test scores in one observation then I would recommend using a data step to make them uniquely identifiable. Use `by`, `testnum.first`, `retain`, and a simple counter to assign each score a `retake` number. Now your transpose uses `retake` *and* `testnum` as `id` variables. You should be able to figure it out from there.

Really hoping right now that I didn't just do your SAS homework assignment for you.

Comment: You could create a format to group testnum, which would avoid the need to create the extra variable.  Proc Means will group by formatted values.

Comment: Excellent point, @Keith. I will add that option to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I was trying to do.  I was originally planning to just take the last.student if I was able to get my data to look like above in my example, leaving me with one row per student with avg12 in 1 column and avg34 in another column, but this worked great.  This wasnt a homework problem so no worries.